# MVC - Change Label(s) on DropDown Selection - Strongly Typed View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**MODEL - Employee.cs**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> lstEmployees { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER - EmpController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.lstEmployees = new List<Employee>();
        emp.lstEmployees.Add(new Employee() { id = 1, name = "ABCD", age = 15 });
        emp.lstEmployees.Add(new Employee() { id = 2, name = "EFGH", age = 25 });
        emp.lstEmployees.Add(new Employee() { id = 3, name = "IJKL", age = 35 });

        ViewBag.EmpList = emp.lstEmployees;

        return View();
    }
```

**VIEW - Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, new SelectList(ViewBag.EmpList, "id", "name"), new { onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged(this)" })


   <script type="text/javascript">
   function SelectedIndexChanged(p) {

   }
   </script>
```

I want to display age at label 
`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.age)` 
on change of selection of drop down.

Comment: try the answer which i have given ,, and let me know..

Comment: check the edited answer which i have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SelectedIndexChanged(element) {
     var optionSelected = $("option:selected", element);
     var selectedAge = $(optionSelected).attr('data-age');
     $('label[for="age"]').text(selectedAge);
  }
</script>
```

It will add the label text with dropdown value.. 
Also you can try with this: `$('label[for="age"]').html(selectedAge);`

Edited:

```
<select name="id" id="id" onchange="SelectedIndexChanged(this)">
  @if(ViewBag.EmpList != null)
  {
      foreach(var item in ViewBag.EmpList){
          <option value="@item.id" data-age="@item.age">@item.name</option>
      }
  }
</select>
```

Comment: Man he want only **age** not whole value